# Problem with calling drupal_get_form from an AJAX callback

Tags: ajax

So, I have a paged, AJAX-enabled list view of entities. As a part of the entity build process for rendering, an AJAX comment form is built, rendered and attached to it.

Now, when I move to the second page in the view (retrieved via AJAX), the comment form shows up but the AJAX property is not attached to it anymore. I used Drupal 7's #ajax on the submit button. Also, the form action is now set to views/ajax when I want it to be the same as the original page. Any way to get around these two issues?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that `Drupal.attachBehaviors()` is called from your AJAX callback. See [Drupal 7 JavaScript API](http://drupal.org/node/751744) for more details.